# Creation Of GroupItems in MetroApps using HTML & Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, windows-8, microsoft-metro, visual-studio-2012

I am using Windows 8 and Visual Studio 2012 RC for Metro apps Development.

Here I am taking `GridApplication` template for creating 3 listviews (*groupedItems*), these 3 listviews will need to display different information from my service. Actually in default grid application they have given common items for all listviews, but **here I do not want to display images for second listview**, when I removed background image variable in javascript file it is showing like empty-image symbol (cf. screenshot)

Below I am trying to give my application scenario.

Can anyone help me to get my output?

Thank you.
[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

You need to modify the template in HTML

```
<div class="itemtemplate" data-win-control="WinJS.Binding.Template">
    <img class="item-image" src="#" data-win-bind="src: backgroundImage; alt: title" />
    <div class="item-overlay">
        <h4 class="item-title" data-win-bind="textContent: title"></h4>
        <h6 class="item-subtitle win-type-ellipsis" data-win-bind="textContent: subtitle"></h6>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="itemtemplatenoimage" data-win-control="WinJS.Binding.Template">
<div class="item-overlay">
        <h4 class="item-title" data-win-bind="textContent: title"></h4>
        <h6 class="item-subtitle win-type-ellipsis" data-win-bind="textContent: subtitle"></h6>
    </div>
</div>
```

then wherever you specify the itemtemplate, specify a different one for each

```
firstListView.itemTemplate = element.querySelector(".itemtemplate");
secondListView.itemTemplate = element.querySelector(".itemtemplatenoimage");
```

Comment: @ gswin thank you for ur reply,Actually here if i remove image tag in my html,it is effecting on Group-1 and Group-3 also.so i want to maintain no-relation between these 3 groups.Any other Item-templates are there to separate those groups?

Comment: yeah you basically need an itemtemplate for each different style you want to use.

Comment: @ gswin, Can u provide me some html to get above output scenario?Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the `ListView` items dynamically in Javascript and apply different CSS to each of your `ListView` item by checking the items "group" property.

```
function listViewItemTemplate(item) {
    // data has has information about each item
    var data = item.data._value;

    var itemElement = document.createElement('div');
    itemElement.id = 'testElement';

    if (data.group === "group1") {
        itemElement.class = "cssForGroup1"; 
        var image = document.createElement('image');
        image.src = "you_file_path";
        image.css = "imageCssForGroup1";
        itemElement.append(image);
    } else if (data.group === "group2") {
        itemElement.class = "cssForGroup2";
    }
    ...
    else {
        ...
    }

    return {element: itemElement}
}

...
// Then you can assign the template to your listview
youListViewControl.itemTemplate = listViewItemTemplate;
```