# Creation of 2 ListViews in Metro App using HTML & Javascript

Tags: html, microsoft-metro, visual-studio-2012, winjs

Iam trying to create 2 Listviews with different information in a single html file.But, here if i modify one listview it is effecting on other listview also. But I need to maintain 2 listviews with different service information?Am using Visual-studio-2012RC and windows8.Any working examples are really helpful to me.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="headerTemplate" data-win-control="WinJS.Binding.Template">
    <p class="group-title win-type-x-large" data-win-bind="textContent: title; groupKey: key" 
        onclick="WinJS.Navigation.navigate('/pages/groupDetail/groupDetail.html', { groupKey: event.srcElement.groupKey })" role="link"></p>
</div>
<div class="itemtemplate" data-win-control="WinJS.Binding.Template">
    <img class="item-image" src="#" data-win-bind="src: backgroundImage" style="-ms-grid-column-span: 1;"/>
    <div class="item-overlay">
        <h5 class="item-title" data-win-bind="textContent: title"></h5>
        <h4 class="item-subtitle win-type-ellipsis" data-win-bind="textContent: subtitle"></h4>
        <h6 class="group-content" data-win-bind="textContent:content" style="margin-left: 2px; margin-right: -13.5px; -ms-grid-row-span: 2; -ms-grid-row:4;" ></h6>
       </div>
</div>

<!-- The content that will be loaded and displayed. -->
<div class="fragment groupeditemspage">
    <header aria-label="Header content" role="banner">
        <button class="win-backbutton" aria-label="Back" disabled></button>
        <h1 class="titlearea win-type-ellipsis">
            <span class="pagetitle">DealFoundry</span>
        </h1>
    </header>
    <section aria-label="Main content" role="main">
        <div class="groupeditemslist" aria-label="List of groups" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.ListView" data-win-options="{selectionmode:'all'}" style="left: 1.5px; top: -1.5px;"></div>
    </section>
    </div>
```

Here is my javascript file(data.js):

```
    (function () {
    "use strict";

    var groupDescription = "Group Description: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ";
    var itemDescription = "Item Description:This is the Item Description";
    var content1 = "Task assigned to James";
    // backgroundImage property in your real data to be URLs to images.
    var lightGray = "ms-appx:///images/microsoft-logo.png";
    // Each of these sample groups must have a unique key to be displayed
    // separately.
    var sampleGroups = [
        { key: "group1", title: "Group-1", subtitle: "Tasks", backgroundImage: darkGray, description: groupDescription },
        { key: "group2", title: "Group-2", subtitle: "Today Deals",backgroundImage: darkGray, description: groupDescription}
          ];

    // Each of these sample items should have a reference to a particular
    // group.
    var sampleItems = [
        { group: sampleGroups[0], title: "John Smith", subtitle: "LesliHart (QR-2157DEF)", description: itemDescription,  backgroundImage: lightGray,content:"Application has been re-assigned"},
        { group: sampleGroups[0], title: "Anna J Fox", subtitle: "Samn Snooker (QNB-1256ABC)", description: itemDescription,  backgroundImage: darkGray,content:"Application rejected"},
        { group: sampleGroups[0], title: "Masson Greeves", subtitle: "Jhonty Rodes (ARN-7854AD)", description: itemDescription,  backgroundImage: mediumGray,content:"Application accepted"},
        { group: sampleGroups[0], title: "Peter Dormain", subtitle: "Glen McGrath (HCL-4567ADE)", description: itemDescription,  backgroundImage: msGray,content:"Application has been re-assigned as the UW is not available for next 2 weeks" },
       { group: sampleGroups[1], title: "Jenni Scott", subtitle: "Jhonty Rodes (ARN-7854AD)", description: itemDescription , content: "Status:Application has been re-assigned as the UW is not available for next 2 weeks" },
       { group: sampleGroups[1], title: "John Smith", subtitle: "James Gosling (IBM - 8569PNM)", description: itemDescription, content: "Status:Application accepted" },
    // Get a reference for an item, using the group key and item title as a
    // unique reference to the item that can be easily serialized.
    function getItemReference(item) {
        return [item.group.key, item.title];

    }

    function resolveGroupReference(key) {
        for (var i = 0; i < groupedItems.groups.length; i++) {
            if (groupedItems.groups.getAt(i).key === key) {
                return groupedItems.groups.getAt(i);
            }
        }
    }

    function resolveItemReference(reference) {
        for (var i = 0; i < groupedItems.length; i++) {
            var item = groupedItems.getAt(i);
            if (item.group.key === reference[0] && item.title === reference[1]) {
                return item;
            }
        }
    }

    // This function returns a WinJS.Binding.List containing only the items
    // that belong to the provided group.
    function getItemsFromGroup(group) {
        return list.createFiltered(function (item) { return item.group.key === group.key; });
    }

    var list = new WinJS.Binding.List();
    var groupedItems = list.createGrouped(
        function groupKeySelector(item) { return item.group.key; },
        function groupDataSelector(item) { return item.group; }
    );

    // TODO: Replace the data with your real data.
    // You can add data from asynchronous sources whenever it becomes available.
    sampleItems.forEach(function (item) {
        list.push(item);

    });

    WinJS.Namespace.define("Data", {
        items: groupedItems,
        groups: groupedItems.groups,
        getItemsFromGroup: getItemsFromGroup,
        getItemReference: getItemReference,
        resolveGroupReference: resolveGroupReference,
        resolveItemReference: resolveItemReference

    });

})();
```

Here i try to give u my application,If i remove image in my second-group it is effecting on group-1 also.But i need to set image for Group-1 and no-image required for Group-2?What should i do for my scenario?
Thank u in advance.

Comment: Could you show the code you used? I think you're binding both the listviews to the same data source.

Comment: @ Jatajuuf ,I hav given my code above,Can u help me to get my application scenario?Thank you

Comment: Your HTML only has one listview in it, and you've only posted the boilerplate data.js generated by the template. Do you have something more like what you're actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: @ Thanku Chris,Here iam trying to give u my output scenario,can u help to get this output?Thank u.    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11017161/creation-of-groupitems-in-metroapps-using-html-javascript

Comment: this question is just impossible to answer without the right code.